# List of non-isomorphic trees on (up to $21$ vertices)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I've been doing some brute force searches to find trees with a certain property and I've run out of convenient lists of trees I can check. For up to 13 vertices, I've been using the list of chordal graphs from this website: [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html) - does anyone have or know how I could (easily) generate a list of non-isomorphic trees on 14+ vertices? My programming skills are still a work in progress, so I'm somewhat limited in the algorithms I can implement. There are about $2,000,000$ non-isomorphic on $21$ vertices, which is about all I can brute force search so if anyone knows of a list up to $21$ vertices, I would be very grateful.

Comment: More precisely, a(21)=2144505 from [OEIS sequence A000055](https://oeis.org/A000055) which has much more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same website, there's [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/trees.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/trees.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Install sage. 2. trxxi = list(graphs.trees(21))